# LOAD DATA INFILE mysql PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

Is there a something I am missing with `LOCAL DATA INFILE`?

My sql code,

```
LOAD DATA 
IGNORE INFILE 
'./infile.txt' 
INTO TABLE table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES STARTING BY '\n'
```

The `infile.txt` is in the same directory as this script, I cannot use `LOCAL` my server won't let me, why is it not working? Is there a way I can check to see if I have it enabled?

I can run `LOCAL` from inside phpMyAdmin and the code works but only inserts 46 rows of about 500,000!

Thanks :)

Comment: What *specific* error is MySQL throwing?

Comment: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'web96-magnetmole'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: But I can do normal statements below it!!

Comment: It sounds like your user does not have 'FILE' privileges ...

Comment: Try this it work for me : [Cannot load data to MySQL database with LOAD DATA INFILE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014508/cannot-load-data-to-mysql-database-with-load-data-infile/13422552#13422552