# Cannot load data to MySQL database with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am using LAMP in Ubuntu 12.04. I created a new user in MySQL (myserver@localhost) and granted ALL on a database to that user. There is a text file the permission of which is set to read for everyone. But when I try to load the data from that text file to the database, it says "Access denied for user 'myserver'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

The query I used is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "~/text/member_info.txt" INTO TABLE member FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

I can think of a workaround with some loops in PHP but why doesn't the 'LOAD DATA INFILE' work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using?

Comment: Check the password. Is it correct?

Comment: I added the query to the question @ Nico

Comment: Which password? I logged in to MySQL with the password and it was correct no problem.@Devart

Comment: It appears you are logging in with user: 'myserver' and pass: 'whatever your pass is'. Please check these credentials - the error is exactly as it says.

Comment: Please see this post: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,12298,12298#msg-12298. And do a bit of googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due the MYSQL 5.5 version you are using in Ubuntu LTS 12.04 : [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html)

From mysql doc comment :

> You can use LOAD DATA LOCAL with recent versions of PHP without
>   recompiling PHP.
>
> Passing 128 (the value of the CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES constant) as the
>   fifth parameter to mysql_connect () enables LOAD DATA LOCAL on the
>   client side.
>
> Example: $dbh = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass, false, 128);
>
> For PHP 4.3 and above.

But in fact, mysql_connect() is obsolete, and I can't find a solution using mysqli.

That's why I finally use [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,12298,266964#msg-266964) who solve the problem.

```
grant file on *.* to mydatabase@localhost identified by 'myuser';
```

Now $mysqli->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '".$proxy_file_name_path."' IGNORE INTO TABLE `mytable` (myfield)"